# SQL Table New Column

Tags: sql

I have an existing table in SQL that includes an ID column. I need to have another Textcolumn in same table in a way it is always equal to ID value but stored as text. For now I am updating Textcolumn daily but I want it to be auto filled.

Is that possible?

Comment: Select **one** DBMS - MySQL and SQL Server are two different servers, with different SQL dialects.

Comment: This makes no sense. If you need string-type ID representation then cast it in a query.

Comment: you will be use computed column in sql server

Comment: I've removing the conflicting RDBMS tags - feel free to add **one** back.

Answer (score 2):

I actually just recommend that you select your `ID` column as text if you have that requirement:

```sql
SELECT ID, CAST(ID AS varchar(55)) ID_text
FROM yourTable;
```

If you need to work this `ID` column as text, then cast as do whatever you need, e.g. a string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do the job.

1. From now on during insert it into the column by casting it as `varchar`.
2. You can use trigger for updating the column. For more information creating trigger are in the [following link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=A%20trigger%20is%20a%20special,manipulation%20language%20(DML)%20event.&text=SQL%20Server%20lets%20you%20create%20multiple%20triggers%20for%20any%20specific%20statement.)

Comment: *You can use trigger for updating the column.* DBMS-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

you can use computed column for solve your problem automatically

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [Idtext]  AS (cast ([id] as nvarchar(10)))
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

this is my sample table

in my sample table the IdText Column fill automatics when you insert a record in your table

if you wants to add column on the existing table you can use this command

```
ALTER TABLE [Table Name] ADD [Column Name] AS (cast([id] as nvarchar(10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Trigger to update it automatically.